# Matplotlib in PySide commercial Application

Tags: python, matplotlib, licensing

I read on matplotlib website, that LGPL on the base code (PySide) isn't compatible with matplotlib license

http://matplotlib.org/devel/license.html#license-discussion

> GPL and LGPL code are not acceptable in the main code base, though we are considering an alternative way of distributing L/GPL code through an separate channel, possibly a toolkit. If you include code, make sure you include a copy of that code’s license in the license directory if the code’s license requires you to distribute the license with it.

Or do they mean the Licence of my Software? so if I use matplotlib, I can't license my software with L/GPL.

My application is commercial and I will have a custom license, I won't publish the source code too, it will be closed-source

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal/licensing question.

Comment: It would be fine to move it to https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ Is it possible? Because this discussion is important even if not fits here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib is licensed under a custom [license](http://matplotlib.org/users/license.html) which is derived from the PSF license which is a [BSD-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Software_Foundation_License) license.  matplotlib and pyside are both compatible with use in commercial programs.

The prohibition of GPL/LGPL in the core code base is that they are both copy-left (viral) licenses (the main difference is that in the case of LGPL simply linking to the library does not make your code LGPL licensed where as linking to GPL code makes the aggregate GPL licensed) where as the main mpl code base is BSD-like, which is not viral.

BSD is GPL compatible, which means you can redistribute BSD code in a project which is over all a GPL/LGPL project (as required by those licenses).

That said, I am not a lawyer and even if I were I am not your layer.  If you are concerned about this, find a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

The section you are referring to only refers to new code brought into matplotlib. I.e matplotlib developers cannot add code to the matplot lib codebase unless it is of compatible license.

Both pyside and the matplotlib license does to me seem to be ok with what you want to do.

DISCLAIMER: IANAL, not even qualified to play one on TV